# How to add column values in Bootstrap Data Tables

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, bootstrap-table

I m using `Bootstrap DataTable` to show mysql records. It has search button and when the user enter values then the table returns corresponding values only.

Demo : http://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap-simple.html

now is it possible to add particular column all data. In the above example there will be salary column. Now I need to add all the 57 peoples salary and show it as Total . And Also when the table change the values also has to change simultaneously.

Please Some on help :) Thanks

```
                  $result22=mysql_query("select * from cont_details");
                        if(mysql_num_rows($result22)>0)
                        {
                        while($row22=mysql_fetch_array($result22))
                        {?>
    <tr <?php $line_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cont_sold  WHERE cont_details_id= '".$row22['cont_details_id']."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($line_qry)>0)echo'style="color:green;"'  ?>>

        <td><?php  echo $row22['cont_no']; $cont_details_id5 = $row22['cont_details_id']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?PHP 
                $qry7 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM depot_charges WHERE
                `cont_details_id` = '$cont_details_id5' order by (str_to_date(`gate_in`,'%d-%m-%Y')) desc LIMIT 1");
                $row7 = mysql_fetch_array($qry7);
                $depot_details_id = $row7['depot_details_id'];

                $qry8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM depot_details WHERE `depot_details_id` = '$depot_details_id'");
                $row8 = mysql_fetch_array($qry8);
                echo $depot_name = $row8['depot_name'];
             ?>
         </td>
        <td>
           <?PHP $row8['depot_charge']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?PHP $row8['depot_handling']; // ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?PHP $row8['depot_repair'];     ?>
        </td>
        <td> 
           <?PHP  $row8['depot_place'];  ?>
        </td>
         <td><?php $row8['cont_price'];  ?></td>
        <td>
          <?php  ?>
        </td>

        <td><?php  echo $row8['cont_other'];  ?></td>

        <td>
            <?PHP $row8['total'];   ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

                        <?php 

                        } ?>
```

Here I need add Total column.

Comment: What have you tried already? If you could post examples of the code you've tried that may help to diagnose where you need help.

Comment: post your HTML, Script and code

Comment: i dont have any idea in this datatables. just checked forums and google but i dont know what to do, so posted question.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis check the code, just simple php code